# How can I get this type of data in Go lang?

Tags: go

This is API response data, looks like this.

```
{   
    "result":1,
    "message":"",
    "pds": [
                {
                    "state":"Y",
                    "code":13,
                    "name":"AAA",
                    "price":39900,
                },
                {
                    "state":"Y",
                    "code":12,
                    "name":"BBB",
                    "price":38000,
                }
            ],
    "request":
            {
                "op":"new",
            }
}
```

How can I get this data in Go lang?
I tried `json.Unmarshall` and get with `map[string]interface{}` but it looks like I used the wrong type to get the data.
Should I use structure??

Comment: Declare a Go type that matches the structure of the JSON document. The [json package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) describes how JSON entities are mapped to Go types..  A short summary is that JSON objects map to `struct` or maps, JSON arrays map to slices or arrays.  See  also: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: ohhhh... thank you, the site helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a struct to handle this properly if you don't want the `json.Unmarshall` output to be a `map[string]interface{}`.

If you map this JSON object to a Go struct you find the following structure:

```
type APIResponse struct {
    Result  int    `json:"result"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Pds     []struct {
        State string     `json:"state"`
        Code  int        `json:"code"`
        Name  string     `json:"name"`
        Price float64    `json:"price"`
    } `json:"pds"`
    Request struct {
        Op string `json:"op"`
    } `json:"request"`
}
```

You also can find a great tool to convert JSON objects to Go structs [here](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/)

Comment: Actually, I kinda wanted to make a common method that calls API to get response data. So, according to your answer, I cannot use a kinda common method to get any data, I should use a "particular" struct to get response data from API. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jiwon A common method is possible.  Follow the pattern of the json.Unmarshal function:  write a function that takes a pointer to the destination value as an `interface{}`.  Pass that `interface{}` value along to json.Unmarshal.

Comment: @Zombo I...don't get it. Do you mean I can use just interface type to get the data??

Comment: @Jiwon The best way to parse the response with a common method is to use a map as you show in your question. But if you want to handle a response with a safer option, you should create a struct type that matches the response you receive from the endpoint you are requesting.

Comment: @RaphaelSalomao I tried to use `map[string]interface{}` type at first, but it showed I am using the wrong data type, so I had to ask here. Actually, I don't want to specify the struct because the data I wanna get from the API would be a single data or an array, and I would use many types from the inside of the data.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use the native `json.Unmarshall`, here's a good option  to use the package [go-simplejson](https://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson).

[Documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bitly/go-simplejson)